# What could be possible reason of given error while laravel setup in nginx ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am deploying Laravel application to NGINX UBUNTU following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I have followed everything exactly. Nginx is working and running. Composer 2.1.11 is installed. Php 8.0.12 is there as well. After following everything step by step, when I hit IP in browser I get **500 internal server error**.
I checked nginx logs and found this:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/travel_list/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30
```

I am not sure what does that means and have googled it and have tried suggested solutions but nothing is working.

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
}
```

Does any lad has any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: "_Php 2.0.12_"??

Comment: What is your PHP version exactly?

Comment: it's related to psr/log v3 requires php 8 and i guess you are using php 7 try using composer without using --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: @brombeer 
My mistake, its PHP 8.0.12

Comment: @PejmanKheyri My mistake, its PHP 8.0.12

Comment: Run php -v and get phpinfo in browser. what are the values?

Comment: @PejmanKheyri Thanks for reply.

php -v is 8.0.12
and phpinfo is giving PHP 7.4.25 - why is it?
Now what should I do

Comment: @YoussefSaoubou I did.. and it went well but site is still not opening

Comment: If `phpinfo` lists that 7.4.25 is used, you are obviously not using PHP 8. Either downgrade the packages you are using to be compatible with that, or upgrade your server such that it uses PHP 8 properly

Answer (score 0):

Nico suggestion was right, so I upgraded the server such that it uses PHP 8 properly by;

```
sudo apt install php8.0-fpm
```

Then I went to my conf file by:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/your.conf
```

The line you need to modify will look like this…

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

You need to replace the old PHP version with the new version.

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
```

Test your configration.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Save the file and exit the editor and restart Nginx for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```